# Mongodb slaveOk - preferred server

Tags: mongodb

Assume I have N servers, each operating as a web server and a mongodb member of a replica set.

I'd like the slaveOk reads to be satisfied first by the local mongodb instance, rather than a remote machine across the network.

The documentation says slaveOk reads are satisfied by an arbitrary member.  Is it possible to override that?

Mongodb 1.8, C-sharp driver 1.2.

Comment: I think using tags or `nearest` with [cursor.readPref()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.readPref/#cursor.readPref) may be what you were after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation says slaveOk reads are satisfied by an arbitrary member. Is it possible to override that?

Not without changing the C# driver. You'd probably have to look somewhere in [this file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Driver/Core/MongoServer.cs#L906) to make those changes.

> Assume I have N servers, each operating as a web server and a mongodb member of a replica set.

As a note, this is generally not the expected usage for MongoDB. Implemented in this way, your web server will be competing for RAM with MongoDB. If a server gets overloaded the web server will starve the `mongod` process which will cause connections to back up and exacerbate the issue.

It sounds like you're trying to use MongoDB as a local cache and there are far better tools for this job.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Not really using as local cache, just  trying to make sure that unnecessary network calls are avoided if the data happens to be local anyway for failover reasons.

Comment: The problem here Nik, tends to be speed & memory. If you direct connect to a local server (bypass the replication), then your local server will have to fetch the actual data. If your local server has this in RAM, then it's fast, but if it's not in RAM, then you might as well use the network to read from someone else.

Comment: Thanks yes. In the configuration as described, they're all web servers.  So the chance of it being in another machine's RAM is the same as it being in local RAM, if they're equally load balanced.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could come to what you are describing is for each web application to open a separate direct connection (not in replica set mode) to the local mongodb and use that separate connection for reads.